# wget not doing what its supposed to do

Tags: wget

I have a simple batch file which is supposed to install Flash by going to the website and selecting the download button. However what it does is entirely different: it goes to the website and the site downloads two folders, neither of which have the download in them.

Can someone give me some direction so that I can get this script working? I am pretty desperate for a solution that will click the download button so that I do not have to perform this operation on all the computer and/or servers in my department.

Let me know if my syntax is incorrect or if I am not even in the right ball park.

Here's the script:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO INSTALLING ADOBE FLASH PLAYER ACTIVE X
ECHO.
start iexplore.exe http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/
wget -drc get.adobe.com/flashplayer/download/ 
pause
ECHO.
ECHO COMPLETE!
EXITcode here
```

Comment: Um... last time I checked, wget doesn't click buttons for you.

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is outside the scope of a simple script/batch file using wget.  You should use the re-distributable version of Flash player.

[This Adobe site](http://www.adobe.com/products/players/fpsh_distribution1.html) has the relevant detail.  Complete the form and follow their instructions.

Answer (score 1):

As @tyler said you could use Autoit to make script what you want easily.
You only need to download autoit and write the following script and compile it.

```
#include <Constants.au3>
If $CmdLine[0] <> 2 Then Exit (1)

Local $URL= $CmdLine[1] ; The first console parameter.
local $Path=$CmdLine[2] ; The second console parameter.

InetGet($URL,$Path);
```

[download autoit](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/)

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use AutoIt to create an executable that you include with your batch file that would detect the adobe download page and automate the process from there.